# Use str_repeat in PHP on an array for events on a particular day in a calendar

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, calendar

Ok I am using a script i found on http://davidwalsh.name/php-calendar  for creating an managing a calendar.  Currently I have reached the point were we are to query the database for events.

```
   /** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/

 $fulldate = strtotime("$month/$list_day/$year");

 mysql_select_db($database_dbconnect, $dbconnect);
 $query_cal = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE startdate > '$fulldate' AND enddate < '$fulldate' AND status = '1' ORDER BY eventtime DESC";
 $caldetails = mysql_query($query_cal, $dbconnect) or die(mysql_error());
 $cal = mysql_fetch_assoc($caldetails);
```

Now I have my events in an array.  The next line im presented with is

```
  $calendar.= str_repeat('',1);
```

Now I'm not understanding how im supposed to get my events into that line?I tried using a do or while loop but everything fails.  How do I get my array into the str_repeat?

Comment: It seems you have a problem in sql query — you select entries with startdate which is older than enddate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

str_repeat() is there only for stub. You should probably write something like:

```
while ($cal = mysql_fetch_assoc($caldetails)) {
    $calendar .= "<p>" . $cal['eventtime'] . ' — ' . $cal['title'] . "</p>";
}
```

BTW check your SQL query. It seems for me it will return zero results always and it probably should be something like

```
$fulldate_tomorrow = $fulldate+86400;
$query_cal = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE startdate >= '$fulldate' AND enddate < '$fulldate_tomorrow' AND status = '1' ORDER BY eventtime DESC";
```